# Why does the apple Review team see my app blank?

Tags: review

[image]my app was rejected because apple saw it as a blank tab bar app, and all it did was load the first and second tab, with none of the images or text or anything else I coded! Does anyone know why apple sees it different than I do? Someone please help me out! I need to figure this issue out! I will really appreciate any help because This is my first app, and I am very anxious! Thank you

Apple sees my app as the blank image above, when really it really looks like the other image.

[image]

Comment: Your questions is a bit vague... Can you put here some details? maybe screenshots?

Comment: I added some screenshots!

Comment: Anyone? Suggestions are welcomed! Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had Universal as the devices instead of iPhone